# Не получается настроить кодировку в MySQL

Tags: android, mysql, кодировка, jdbc, utf-8

Я передаю JsonObject, состоящий из объектов типа String, из android-приложения на сервер через POST-запрос и сохраняю переменные в MySQL c помощью JDBC. Если в переменных String содержатся только английские буквы, всё работает правильно. Но при попытке сохранить кириллицу или символы "Ç", "ẞ" и т.д. сервер выдаёт ошибку:

`Incorrect string value: '\xC2\x92 \xC3\x91\xC2...' for column 'contacts' at row 1`

Что я уже сделал:

- Установил Text file encoding в UTF-8 в Eclipse->Window->Preferences->Workspace
- Установил UTF-8 как Default encoding для всех типов контента в Eclipse->Window->Preferences->General->Content Types
- Заменил DB_URL на `"jdbc:mysql://localhost/YOURWAY?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8"` До этого действия, MySQL сохранял кириллицу, но частично, в виде: "Доб??о??е ут??о"

UPDATE:

- Заменил кодировку всех таблиц и базы данных командами: `ALTER DATABASE название_базы CHARACTER SET = utf8mb4 COLLATE = utf8mb4_unicode_ci;` и `ALTER TABLE название_таблицы CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;`
- Заменил DB_URL на "jdbc:mysql://localhost/YOURWAY?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8&character_set_server=utf8mb4"

Ошибка больше не вылетает, но теперь при вызове `SELECT * FROM название_базы` MySQL выдаёт что-то вроде "ÃÂÃÂ°ÃÂ²ÃÂ°ÃÂ¹ ÃÂ´ÃÂÃÂÃÂ¶ÃÂ¸ÃÂÃÂ!". При этом, если получить эти данные на Android чере GET-запрос, на Android снова отображается "Доб??о??е ут??о".

Что я упускаю из виду?

Comment: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/users?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8&amp;characterSetResults=UTF-8

Comment: и кодировку в mysql при установке установите на utf-8 general-c

Comment: @ЭмЭрИкс_007    Объясните, пожалуйста, подробнее. Мне вернуть кодировку таблиц и базы данных в utf8? Как установить кодировку при установке?

Comment: после установки попросит запустить программу (настройщик) mysql.В ней задаются все параметры : пароль,переменная для среды и.т.д.Вот там и есть пункт выборки кодировки.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/file/?id=474441

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Итак, я нашёл проблему. Это касалось вовсе не MySQL.

Проблема была в библиотеке okhttp в составе retrofit2, которые я использую для общения с сервером. Okhttp не позволяет напрямую передавать кириллицу в GET и POST запросах. Чтобы обойти это ограничение, я добавил кодирование перед передачей данных на сервер с помощью `URLEncoder.encode(строка, "UTF-8");` и декодирование после приема данных с сервера с помощью `URLDecoder.decode(строка, "UTF-8");`. Кроме того, понадобилось увеличить длину всех столбцов VARCHAR в MySQL в три раза (т.к. один символ кириллицы в String соответствует трём символам в UTF-8). Надеюсь, мой опыт поможет кому-то ещё.